# Warning with React form: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `validate`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I would like to try to get rid of this warning

> index.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `validate`.
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: validate="true" or validate={value.toString()}.

I'm making a validation form for subscribing users. I show tooltip, when the email field is not filled out and the user tries to press the subscribe button.

Here is my form (using Material UI styling):

```
<Form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              initialValues={{ userEmail: 'johndoe@example.com', arn: 'AA-01-23-45-678901-2' }}
              validate={validate}
              render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} validate>

                <DialogContentText>
                  To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
                  occasionally.
                </DialogContentText>

                <TextField
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="userEmail"
                  margin="none"
                  required={true}
                  fullWidth
                />

                {formSubmitted && <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Typography name='submitMessage' variant='subtitle1'>You have subscribed to {values.arn}. {/* Connect to backend here */}</Typography>
                </Grid>}

                <DialogActions>
                  <Button /* onClick={handleClose} */ color="primary" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                    Subscribe
                  </Button>
                  <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>

              </form>
              )}
            />
```

And my validate function outside of the component function but within the same js file:

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.userEmail) {
    errors.userEmail = 'Required';
  }
  return errors;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the problem ended up being with the validation function I was using within the Form tags!